# 4TB drives not working using the same backup process that works with 2TB ones

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-disk

I've been using an ICY BOX 2-bay RAID box for backing up my work for some years without any problem. I use WD 2Tb 3,5 drives in RAID 1 mode.

This year I started using 4TB drives of the same brand. To my surprise, the drives can only be accessed when they are both in the ICY BOX, not individually when I put them in a SATA docking bay as I always did with the 2TB ones.

When I connect the drive the Mac says it can't access the drive. I've run First Aid in Disk Utility but didn't work either.

I'm using MacBook Pro M1, disks are formatted in Mac OS Extended (Journaled), Big Sur 11.5.2

Already checked with different cables, docking bays, external drive enclosures, etc.

Comment: The drives being accessible when NOT in the RAID unit is the abnormal state.  I would not expect them to be.